# how to get visitor location from my site web (Javascript or PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation

how to get users location from my site web (Javascript or PHP) I want to be precise enough.
A website that uses from phones a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get client's IP address using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript)

Comment: That's not a duplicate of getting ***IP address***. This is about getting the ***geographical location***.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect country and city using PHP, GeoIP and Maxmind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642598/how-to-detect-country-and-city-using-php-geoip-and-maxmind)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php) for php. There is also lite version which is free.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of geolocation libraries for PHP and Javascript, you can try using the following sources in PHP scripts, they also have a steps to installing and configuring the service:

[MaxMind](http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-php/)

[IP2Location](https://www.ip2location.com/developers/php-api)